# class of time in r; The criteria for this is when < 12:00:00 is morning and when is > 12:00:00 is the afternoon

Tags: r, date

I need to create a column as from as a time column. The criteria for this is when < 12:00:00 is morning and when is > 12:00:00 is the afternoon. I used

```
behaviour2$Shift <- cut(behaviour2$Time, include.lowest = TRUE, c(00:00:00, 12:00:00), labels = c('Mor', 'aft'))
```

but has error.

Data:

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1542013077, 1542013078, 1542013080, 1542013081, 1542013081, 1542013083, 1542013085, 1542013086, 1542013088, 1542013088), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), IC4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Time", "IC4"), row.names = 142320:142329, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time object to categorical (morning, afternoon, evening, night) variable in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370387/convert-time-object-to-categorical-morning-afternoon-evening-night-variable)

Answer (score 0):

`%p` in `format` means AM/PM:

```
behaviour2$Shift <- format(behaviour$Time, "%p")
head(behaviour2)

#Time IC4 Shift
#142320 2018-11-12 03:57:57   0    AM
#142321 2018-11-12 03:57:58   0    AM
#142322 2018-11-12 03:58:00   0    AM
#142323 2018-11-12 03:58:01   0    AM
#142324 2018-11-12 03:58:01   0    AM
#142325 2018-11-12 03:58:03   0    AM
```

Comment: I made that but has this error: result in a blank column. PropB300 Shift
13   2.246697   3.627273 0.9090909      
14   2.246697   3.627273 0.9090909      
15   2.278745   3.625000 0.9105691      
16   2.297627   3.628319 0.9112903      
18   2.316510   3.631579 0.9120000      
19   2.316510   3.631579 0.9120000