# Cut day into multiple parts

Tags: r, time, dplyr, timestamp, transform

To find the right aggregation level for my data, I have to split the day into frames of different sizes.

Example data:

```
da = data.frame(timestamp = c("2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT" ,"2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT", "2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT", "2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT", "2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT"))

da
                timestamp
1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT
2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT
3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT
4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT
5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT
```

For example, I could start cutting the day in 24 parts. Then 0:00 to 1:00 is part 1, 1:00 to 2:00 is part 2 etc.

```
da2 = data.frame(timestamp = c("2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT" ,"2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT", "2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT", "2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT", "2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT"),
                 daypart = c(2, 3, 14, 16, 19))
da2
                timestamp daypart
1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT       2
2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT       3
3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT      14
4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT      16
5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT      19
```

Or into 48 parts. Then 0:00 to 0:30 is part 1, 0:30 to 1:00 part 2 etc:

```
da48 = data.frame(timestamp = c("2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT" ,"2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT", "2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT", "2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT", "2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT"),
+                  daypart = c(3, 5, 28, 31, 37))
da48
                timestamp daypart
1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT       3
2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT       5
3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT      28
4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT      31
5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT      37
```

I found this post [Pos on how to convert time to categorical variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370387/convert-time-object-to-categorical-morning-afternoon-evening-night-variable), which has already helpes, but how can I code this in such a way that I only have to change the number of parts I want to cut the day into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn `timestamp` to the `POSIXlt` object and extract hour of time by the `$` symbol.

```
da$daypart <- as.POSIXlt(da$timestamp)$hour + 1

#                 timestamp daypart
# 1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT       2
# 2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT       3
# 3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT      14
# 4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT      16
# 5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT      19
```

---

**Edit:** Split time into 48 parts

```
time <- as.POSIXlt(da$timestamp)
da$daypart48 <- time$hour * 2 + (time$min > 30) + 1
da

#                 timestamp daypart daypart48
# 1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT       2         3
# 2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT       3         5
# 3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT      14        28
# 4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT      16        31
# 5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT      19        37
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would this work if I want to cut the day in 48 parts?

Comment: @Scijens Do you mean 0:00 to 0:30 is part 1, 0:30 to 1:00 is part 2...etc?

Comment: Exactly. I have added the example in the post. The solution of @jay.sf already works, so if it takes a lot of time, I am happy using this one.

Answer (score 2):

You could `strsplit` the time at `:`,

```
(tmp <- do.call(rbind, 
                strsplit(strftime(as.POSIXct(da$timestamp), "%H:%M:%S"), ":")))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "01" "17" "37"
# [2,] "02" "09" "41"
# [3,] "13" "34" "35"
# [4,] "15" "17" "56"
# [5,] "18" "14" "55"
```

calculate in seconds,

```
(sec <- apply(tmp, 2, as.numeric) %*% c(60*60, 60, 1))
#       [,1]
# [1,]  4657
# [2,]  7781
# [3,] 48875
# [4,] 55076
# [5,] 65695
```

and `match` with daily seconds `cut` into 24 pieces.

```
da$daypart <- cut(1:(24*60*60), 24, labels=1:24)[match(sec, 1:(24*60*60))]
```

### Result

```
da
#              timestamp daypart
# 1 2016-01-24 01:17:37 GMT    2
# 2 2016-01-24 02:09:41 GMT    3
# 3 2016-01-24 13:34:35 GMT   14
# 4 2016-01-24 15:17:56 GMT   16
# 5 2016-01-24 18:14:55 GMT   19
```

Comment: Thanks, with this code, I am also not able to make it work for example with 48 parts for a day.

I've tried the following:
da$daypart <- cut(1:(48*60*60), 48, labels=1:48)[match(sec, 1:(48*60*60))]

Comment: @Scijens Daily seconds don't change when increasing the parts, try `cut(1:(24*60*60), 48, labels=1:48)[match(sec, 1:(24*60*60))]`.